# Implementación de método - Sumar valor recibido como parámetro al valor del atributo

Tags: java

Soy nuevo en Java. Tengo la clase `StatisticsTeam` que está compuesta por los siguientes atributos:

```
 - won: int =0
 - drawn: int =0
 - lost: int =0
 - goalsFor: int = 0
 - goalsAgainst: int = 0
 - WON_POINTS: int = 3 (constante)
 - DRAWN_POINTS: int = 1 (constante)
 - LOST_POINTS: int = 0 (constante)
```

La clase StatisticsTeam incluye un conjunto de métodos, entre ellos, los métodos `getGoalsFor() int` y `incGoalsFor(goalsFor: int)`. Para más detalle, adjunto visualización del diagrama UML:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Antes de empezar a codificar los métodos, he codificado los atributos de la siguiente forma:

```
public class StatisticsTeam {
    private int won = 0;
    private int drawn = 0;
    private int lost = 0;
    private int goalsFor = 0;
    private int goalsAgainst = 0;
    private final int won_points = 3;  // final para definirlo como constante
    private final int drawn_points = 1; // final para definirlo como constante
    private final int lost_points = 0; // final para definirlo como constante

    // MÉTODOS 
}
```

Para lo codificación de los métodos getGoalsFor() y incGoalsFor(goalsFor: int), tengo que hacer lo siguiente:

El valor de los goles a favor (`goalsFor`) tiene que ser mayor o igual a cero. En el caso del método `incGoalsFor`, el valor que reciba por parámetro tiene que sumarse al valor que tiene en este momento el atributo `goalsFor` de la instancia. Si el valor que se quiere sumar es negativo, entones `incGoalsFor` no tiene que asignar este valor, y en su lugar, tiene que lanzar la siguiente `Exception`: *[ERROR] The number of goalsFor that you want to add must be greater than or equal to 0*.

He hecho lo siguiente, pero no lo tengo demasiado claro:

```
public int getGoalsFor(){
        return this.incGoalsFor();
    }
    
private void incGoalsFor(int goalsFor) throws Exception {
     if(goalsFor < 0) {
         throw new Exception ("[ERROR] The number of goalsFor you want to add must be greater than or equal to 0");
     } else {
         this.goalsFor = goalsFor + this.goalsFor;
        };
    }
```

Sin embargo, estoy obteniendo el error `incGoalsFor(int) cannot be applied to '()'`. Creo que me estoy dejando algo...

A tener en cuenta, a diferencia que en los setters, en este caso creo que no deberíamos substituir el valor del atributo, sino que tenemos que sumar el valor pasado como argumento al valor que ya tenía el atributo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error te viene en la línea de `return this.incGoalsFor();` donde dejas la función incGoalsFor sin ningún parámetro del tipo int. Se solucionaría poniendo cualquier cariable del tipo int.

---

Con eso se solucionaría el error pero el  `getGoalsFor()` lo tienes mal planteado. Segun entiendo el `getGoalsFor()` te tiene que devolver la variable `goalsFor` lo que quedaría tal que así:

```
public int getGoalsFor(){
    return goalsFor;
}
```

Comment: Puede ser, pero con este cambio. No estoy haciendo nunca uso del método incGoalsFor()

Comment: ¿El metodo incGoalsFor() tiene que ser privado?  ¿solo lo puedes utilizar en tu class StatisticsTeam? porque si no es así con ponerlo en publico se te solucionaría el problema y la lo utilizaras en una class superior. Porque al menos en lo que has puesto no hace referencia a que sea un metodo exclusivo de la class StatisticsTeam